# MOSFET \$I_{ON}\$ formula in the book CMOS VLSI design

Tags: mosfet

[image]

This screenshot is taken from CMOS VLSI Design by Weste and Harris. According to the square (Shockley) model, the current in saturation is given by the following equation:
$$I_{ds} = \frac{\beta}{2} \cdot V_{GD}^2$$
And according to the previously screenshotted paragraph, \$I_{ON}\$ is the current when \$V_{GS} = V_{DD}\$ and \$V_{DS} = V_{DD}\$. This means that it's the maximum current in *saturation*. However, using the previous equation, It can be deduced that
$$I_{on} = \frac{\beta}{2} \cdot (V_{DD} - V_t)^2$$

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Or do you need to review the assumptions for Vt which are near 0 current but in datasheets are std. defined for some threshold current like 200 uA or near abouts.  So Vt is a high impedance leakage threshold but not off but always with Vgs=Vds.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand. could you please elaborate more on how could this answer the question? I'm asking where did the authors derive the equation \$I_{ON} = \frac{\beta}{2} \cdot (V_{GT} - V_T)\$ while the saturation rule for \$I_{ds}\$ has a square.

Comment: Notice the Vgs=Vds=Vdd which is NOT a very useful mode of operation.  There are about 7 different equations and these are the simplest.  Normally datasheets give RdsOn for some Vgs that is typically at least three times Vt or perhaps less for ultra-low sub-threshold types. and maybe 2.5x Vt where rated RdsOn is used for Linear mode which is inverse to transconductance or BETA.  The quadratic effects occur when Vt barely above Vt but not heavily conducting. . The proof must be in one of those books but look at the curves they describe

Comment: All I can say is use the equations I have you for what it's worth but spend more time learning datasheets. https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMN62D0UW.pdf  this is the cheapest MOSFET  For these you wont even find a value for transconductance in A/V^2  but you can see the curves  Transconductance is used in RF parts where you want a square law just above threshold, Vt